# How do I add a custom Help menu to TinyMCE4?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using a custom menu for TinyMCE4. In the initialization call, my menu setup looks like this:

```
menu : {
  ... <other menu sections>
  help:   { title: 'Help',   items: 'help' }
},
```

I was expecting this to yield the following, which is what you get by default or when the Help item is in the menubar property (blue highlighting is mine):

[image: Help Menu]

Instead I get nothing.

How can I manually include the help menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT*** *:  This defect was fixed in TinyMCE 4.7.8 so its no longer correct to name the item `'Help'` -  you should use `'help'` from 4.7.8 onward.*

Due to a defect in TinyMCE you need to use this code:

```
help: { 
    title: 'Help',
    items: 'Help'
}
```

...note the `items` value starts with `H` not `h`.  Here is a working example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Nkgaab/1

The incorrect need to use `Help` will be fixed in a future TinyMCE release at which point you will need to modify the configuration to use `help`.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully I can future-proof by including both the correct and incorrect forms in my script because unknown forms seem to be ignored.